# Passing a parameter with an ampersand to a controller action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view that displays a link of vendors, with a link to each vendor detail page

```
@foreach (var vendor in Model.Vendors)
{
    <li>
        <a href="/Vendors/@(vendor.Name)">@vendor.Name</a>
    </li>
}
```

One particular vendor is named *"ABC Sales & Services"*, so the link to their detail page is `/Vendors/ABC Sales & Services`. When I navigate to that url, I get this error:

> **A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).**

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to `web.config`'s `httpRuntime`:

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidChars="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\,?" />
```

By default that list includes `&amp;`, you are simply removing it

Comment: Also, as @CalvinAllen said on his answer, using the name for the URL is generally not a good practice (unless you have a valid reason for it)

Answer (score 1):

You should really utilize the ID of the vendor (hopefully, there is a primary key - either numeric/guid - on your database), not the name.

Answer (score 1):

You should UrlEncode the vendor name:

```
<a href="/Vendors/@Url.Encode(vendor.Name)">@vendor.Name</a>
```

By the way, this is done on your behalf when you use `Url.Action` or the `Html.Action` methods to construct your anchor tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<a href="@Url.Action("/Vendors/" + @vendor.Name)">@vendor.Name</a>
```